# Qt TrayIcon when Minimizing the Window

Tags: qt, system-tray, minimize

Well i have this piece of code:

```
void MainWindow::event(QEvent *event)
    {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange) {
            if(isMinimized()) {
                trayIcon->show();
                hide();
                event->ignore();
            }else{
                event->accept();
            }
        }
    }
```

Well, basically yes. I'm trying that when the Window is minimized, it creates the tray Icon and hides the application from Taskbar. Whatever, i keep getting "No 'void MainWindow::event(QEvent *)' member function declared in class 'MainWindow'" When the autocomplete shows it.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you declare the override in your class definition?

Comment: When you add a function _definition_ like the code snippet in your question, you also need to _declare_ the function in the class. That would mean adding a line like `void MainWindow::event(QEvent *event);` inside the class which is usually located in a header file.

Comment: Wow, now it seems to be working. Before it didn't. Thank you very much!